# Windows 8 "Split App Project" tiles navigation to a Particular page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am Working On visual studio for metro app development for windows 8 pc .Is it Possible to navigate to "html webpage" when clicked on group1 and to "another webpage" when clicked on group2, when selecting project as "Split App" . In fact i just want to create some group and there transition to different webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code in the item clicked event:

So, instead of the Frame.Navigate in the following code, get the website you want to navigate to from the clicked item and launch it to the web browser

```
    void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
        // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
        var groupId = ((SampleDataGroup)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SplitPage), groupId);
    }
```